# Why is the TaxonomyClientService.asmx service returning escaped XML for my result?

Tags: web-services, jquery, mms, managed-metadata-service

I was able to sucessfully call the service but when I get my results back it looks like this (see the GetChildTermsInTermSetResult node):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetChildTermsInTermSetResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/">
            <GetChildTermsInTermSetResult>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;&lt;TermStore&gt;&lt;T a9="3ebb7649-a9eb-49ce-9589-4caad51ad7d7" a21="false" a61="0"&gt;&lt;LS&gt;&lt;TL a32="1" a31="true" /&gt;&lt;/LS&gt;&lt;DS /&gt;&lt;TMS&gt;&lt;TM a24="9c46e833-5154-4ceb-9dd6-4c0538dab600" a12="AssessorBookPages" a40="" a17="true" a67="" a45="3ebb7649-a9eb-49ce-9589-4caad51ad7d7" a69="true" /&gt;&lt;/TMS&gt;&lt;/T&gt;&lt;T a9="fe4366be-5906-4be0-ae12-a02f0ded885f" a21="false" a61="0"&gt;&lt;LS&gt;&lt;TL a32="2" a31="true" /&gt;&lt;/LS&gt;&lt;DS /&gt;&lt;TMS&gt;&lt;TM a24="9c46e833-5154-4ceb-9dd6-4c0538dab600" a12="AssessorBookPages" a40="" a17="true" a67="" a45="fe4366be-5906-4be0-ae12-a02f0ded885f" a69="true" /&gt;&lt;/TMS&gt;&lt;/T&gt;&lt;T a9="6c38bc09-d345-4ae8-9131-a10731159f15" a21="false" a61="0"&gt;&lt;LS&gt;&lt;TL a32="3" a31="true" /&gt;&lt;/LS&gt;&lt;DS /&gt;&lt;TMS&gt;&lt;TM a24="9c46e833-5154-4ceb-9dd6-4c0538dab600" a12="AssessorBookPages" a40="" a17="true" a67="" a45="6c38bc09-d345-4ae8-9131-a10731159f15" a69="true" /&gt;&lt;/TMS&gt;&lt;/T&gt;&lt;T a9="a9349b48-27dc-4e6c-9c62-ca43d9704e45" a21="false" a61="0"&gt;&lt;LS&gt;&lt;TL a32="4" a31="true" /&gt;&lt;/LS&gt;&lt;DS /&gt;&lt;TMS&gt;&lt;TM a24="9c46e833-5154-4ceb-9dd6-4c0538dab600" a12="AssessorBookPages" a40="" a17="true" a67="" a45="a9349b48-27dc-4e6c-9c62-ca43d9704e45" a69="true" /&gt;&lt;/TMS&gt;&lt;/T&gt;&lt;/TermStore&gt;</GetChildTermsInTermSetResult>
        </GetChildTermsInTermSetResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am using jQuery/AJAX to call this service.  I need to parse this result from my jQuery and have resorted to some pretty hairy shenanigans to try to get it working.

Is it supposed to return GetChildTermsInTermSetResult as escaped XML? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completley correct.

The [GetChildTermsInTermSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.webservices.taxonomyclientservice.getchildtermsintermset.aspx) method returns a string and not a complex type.

Comment: Any idea why they would do that?  They even say: `Returns all child Terms of the TermSet serialized as an XML structure.`  Why not just return xml?

Comment: @Abe, if the returned XML were poorly formed due to a bug, or error in the child terms, then the SOAP packet would be poorly formed and throw nothing but faults/exceptions. I've seen this sort of thing rationalized elsewhere for webservices and I want to slap them.